# JQuery on('click') call function directly instead of defining it inside the event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

```
$('#homeNavBar').on('click', onSiteLoad());

function onSiteLoad() {
    $('#dataHolder').html('');
    userLoginMenu.html('');
    var h1 = $('<h1>').text('Welcome');
    var span = $('<span>').text('Welcome to our book library');
    dataHolder.append(h1).append(span);
}
```

I want to call the function onSiteLoad() directly inside change function.

The only way it lets me do it is like this:

```
$('#homeNavBar').on('click', function () {
    $('#dataHolder').html('');
    userLoginMenu.html('');
    var h1 = $('<h1>').text('Welcome');
    var span = $('<span>').text('Welcome to our book library');
    dataHolder.append(h1).append(span);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the function reference, as of now you are invoking the function as passing its return value an event handler

```
$('#homeNavBar').on('click', onSiteLoad);
                                    //^^^^ Parenthesis removed
```

Comment: ok it worked, but from what i know when it ends up with () you are calling it, otherwise you just save it's value

Comment: @ВсеЕдно Save it's value? When you add parenthesis you call it indeed, without it, it is just a reference to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the external function inside your onClick also.

```
$('#homeNavBar').on('click', function () {
    onSiteLoad();
});
```